# What makes a program load so fast?

Tags: linux, software, linux-development

What makes programs like [st](https://st.suckless.org/), [zathura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(document_viewer)), [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv), and [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) load instantly and what makes programs like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) load so slowly in low-spec computers?

For example, I have a low-spec laptop running Linux Mint. And when I execute **st**, it instantly opens an **st** instance, but when I execute **Google Chrome**, it takes a long time to open a **Google Chrome** instance.
What makes st load faster than Google Chrome and what makes Google Chrome load slower than st.

Thank you! :)

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: surely the st home pages explains this in its xterm vs st intro

Comment: Those applications seem to have different purposes, and were likely developed by teams with different goals. VS Code and Chrome are definitely designed for extensions, which can have a significant impact on load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things which make a program "slow"

1. Doing lots of things.

   Chrome does a lot more stuff than st or your other examples
2. Being big.

   Big programs have more information to load from disk and take up lots of memory. If they use more memory than the computer has available, the OS will swap stuff in memory to disk and then back again. Which is much slower than keeping it all in memory.

   Chrome is a lot bigger than st. Plus it has multiple tabs with all the information held in each.

Answer (score 0):

Some software "phones home" at startup. That is, it checks for updates. Big pieces of software often have many files. Each file might be checked and then the software queries over the internet to check for newer versions.  Network delays can be noticeable.

Comment: While this is true, in any modern application the user should not notice this because all of that would be done lazily, asynchronously, on a separate low-priority thread. Then again, everything adds up.

Comment: @MartinMaat Discord won't start until it's checked for updates.